# Specifying form in MemberQ

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

This seems like a very simple question, the answer to which should be obvious to me.  So I won't be offended if this question is closed.  But I'm having trouble figuring out the answer.

I would like to write a function that returns `True` if a list contains one or more numbers greater than 1.  Why does `MemberQ[{2, 1}, # > 1 &]` return `False`?  Thanks.

Comment: `Select[{2, 1}, # > 1 &] != {}`

Comment: `Catch[Scan[If[# > 1, Throw[True]] &, {1, 2, 6, 8}]]`

Comment: `TakeWhile[#, # <= 1 &] != # &@{1, 2}`

Comment: Simply put, the second argument of `MemberQ[]` should be a *pattern*, not a test. What does `MatchQ[2, # > 1 &]` return?

Comment: The comment by @J.M. answers your question; if you insist on using `MemberQ` you can do `MemberQ[{2, 1}, _?(# > 1 &)]` to transform a test into a pattern.

Comment: `Count[list, x_Integer /; x > 1] > 0`

Comment: The simplest way is clearly `! IntegerQ@Log2[1 + FromDigits[UnitStep[1 - {1, 2}]~Prepend~1, 2]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As J. M. kindly points out, I must specify *form* as a **pattern**, not a test.  Thus, as b.gatessucks kindly points out, I must instead use:

```
MemberQ[{2, 1}, _?(# > 1 &)]
```

or one of the other suggestions given as comments to the original post.